# Hide a value in a cell unless another cell has a given value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-data-validation

I'm trying to create a formula to generate a list of values in a dropdown.

1. Each row contains a **`task`** that has a **`status`**, and a **`priority`**.
2. The **`priority`** is set from a dropdown containing a list of numbers from **`1-50`**.
3. No two **`tasks`** can share the same **`priority`** so the dropdown must exclude any already in use.
4. When a **`task`** has a **`status="done"`**, its **`priority`** is no longer considered in use and should once more be available in the dropdowns.

For example, in the table below,

- the dropdowns are in column A
- The priority **`15`** in **`A4`** should not be excluded from dropdowns because **`C4="Done"`**
- Therefore, the dropdown in **`A6`**, for example, could include **`15`** but would not include any of **`{24, 32, 49}`**

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Priority** | **Task** | **Status** |
| **2** | 32 | A task to complete | In Progress |
| **3** | 24 | Another task | In progress |
| **4** | **`15`** | A completed task | **`Done`** |
| **5** | 49 | A postponed task | On Hold |
| **6** |  | Another task awaiting prioritisation | To Do |

I'm able to eliminate any assigned **`priority`**  from the dropdowns using the following formula, but I can't get to the next step, restoring used values to the dropdown if they are assigned to a **`task`** with **`status="done"`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(
     COUNTIF(
       H2:H1000,A2:A1000)=0,
       H2:H1000,))
```

How would I reinstate a value that was used, such as in **`A4`** of my example, if the **`status`** of that row is set to **`"Done"`**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula somewhere on the same sheet or another sheet and point your dropdown to the column where you place it.

```
=FILTER(
   SEQUENCE(50),
   COUNTIFS(
     A2:A1000, SEQUENCE(50),
     C2:C1000, "<>Done")=0)
```

## Explanation

1. COUNTIFS is used in place of COUNTIF to allow adding the additional criteria `<>Done`.
2. SEQUENCE is used to create the list of numbers from **`1-50`**
3. FILTER removes numbers already in use based on the array of TRUE/FALSE values returned by COUNTIFS.

Comment: perfect, thanks for that, I hadn't considered the sequence function!